# Python: Get data from Binance when the current candle is finished -

Tags: python, pandas, pine-script, binance, binance-api-client

I want to pull the data from binance after 5 minutes candle is completed, no matter what time I will run the app, I have tried the following but that's keep pulling the data every second, I have also thought about going to sleep for 5 minutes but I think this will lead to incompatible data.

```
while True:         
      try:
          for ticker in symbols:
               candles = live.getKlines(Client, symbol=ticker, length=48)
               print(candles)
                   

def getKlines(Client, symbol, length):
    headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36',
               "Connection": "keep-alive",
               "Accept-Encoding": "*"
               }
    payload = {'symbol': symbol, 'interval': '5m', 'limit': '200'}
    result = request.get(
        "https://api.binance.com/api/v3/klines?", headers=headers, params=payload)
    candles = pd.DataFrame(eval(result.content))
    candles.columns = ['Date', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume', 'Close_Time',
                       'Quote_Volume', 'Trades_Count', 'BUY_VOL', 'BUY_VOL_VAL', 'x']    
    candles.insert(loc=1, column="Symbol", value=symbol)  
    candles["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(candles["Date"], unit="ms")
    candles["Close"] = candles["Close"].astype(float)
    candles["Volume"] = candles["Volume"].astype(float)

    return candles
```

Answer (score 0):

If u still need it, I created this method:

```
def get_seconds_to_close(interval):
    candle = get_values_of_current_candle("BTC",interval) ## Here u should use your own method to get the values of the last/current candle (coin doesnt matter here)
    timestamp = candle["time"] ## We use the current candle to get the timestamp aka. opening time of the candle
    if interval=="1m":
        seconds = 60
    elif interval=="5m":
        seconds = 300
    elif interval=="1h":
        seconds = 3600
    elif interval == "4h":
        seconds = 14400
    elif interval == "1d":
        seconds = 24 * 3600
    else:
        print("Interval error!")
        quit()

    current_time = time.time()
    needed_timestamp = timestamp+seconds
    seconds_left = needed_timestamp-current_time
    return seconds_left
```

It will return the seconds left for a new candle opening in the given timeframe ("5m" in your case). You can use this method together with time.sleep(seconds_left) in your loop to pull the data everytime a new candle opens depending on your timeframe.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at the Websocket API documentation perhaps.
This was you can receive latest updates as ready each 5 min candle closes (eg. set 5m to your interval for the websocket: https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#trade-streams